# Webinf/lib folder missing caused error 500 and 404 in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

Why am I getting the  Error instantiating servlet class error? It was working fine until I added a main page.

I have tried cleaning project and serer and rebuilding. Doesn't work. The path seems okay. Can't figure out why.

The error on the web browser

[image]

Web page error

[image]

When I go back and click on submit, I get the 404 error.

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I'm using Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 and Eclipse IDE

My folder structure:

[image]

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JuzzyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.juzzy.client.Choice</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JuzzyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Choice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with my libraries. Went to the problems view on my eclipse and fixed problems in my project. Deleted my jars from all folders, imported them into the webinf/lib folder and added them to my build path. There was nothing wrong wit the code apparently.